# Using str.replace() to fix clipPath case-sensitivity makes SVG file uneditable

Tags: node.js, d3.js, svg, data-visualization

I'm building a Node-powered command line interface to generate SVG maps. I'm having trouble producing SVG files that can be edited in programs like Inkscape, however, which limits the usefulness of the utility.

The issue is that a WebKit error causes D3-generated `clipPath` elements to become all-lowercase `clippath` elements instead, which of course isn't proper SVG and ends up ruining the image. To get around this, I do a global replace to convert it back to camelCase.

That workaround produces an SVG file that can be viewed fine in a browser, but can't be edited in an SVG editing program like Inkscape. If I *don't* do the global replace, the file can be edited just fine.

Any clue how to fix this issue?

GitHub repo, so you can test the CLI yourself: https://github.com/hierocles/housemapper-cli

Relevant code:

```
function makeMap(fileName) {
  var document = jsdom.jsdom();

  var us = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync( __dirname + '/jsonfiles/us.json', 'utf8'));
  var congress = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/jsonfiles/us-cong-114.json', 'utf8'));

  var css = "<![CDATA[ \
      .background { \
        fill: none; \
      } \
      .district { \
        fill: #ccc; \
      } \
      .district-dem-yes { \
        fill: #394DE5; \
      } \
      .district-dem-no { \
        fill: #7585FF; \
      } \
      .district-rep-yes { \
        fill: #EA513C; \
      } \
      .district-rep-no { \
        fill: #EA998F; \
      } \
      .district-yes { \
        fill: #03BC82; \
      } \
      .district-no { \
        fill: #3BE2AD; \
      } \
      .state-boundaries { \
        fill: none; \
        stroke: #fff; \
        stroke-width: 1px; \
      } \
      .district-boundaries { \
        fill: none; \
        stroke: #fff; \
        stroke-width: 0.5px; \
        stroke-linecap: round; \
        stroke-linejoin: round; \
      }\
  ]]>";

  var width = 960,
      height = 500;

  var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
      .scale(1000)
      .translate([width/2, height/2]);

  var path = d3.geo.path()
      .projection(projection);

  var svg = d3.select(document.body).append('svg')
      .attr('xmlns', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height);

      svg.append("rect")
          .attr("class", "background")
          .attr("width", width)
          .attr("height", height);

  var defs = svg.append('defs');

      defs.append('path')
        .attr('id', 'land')
        .datum(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.land))
        .attr('d', path);

      defs.append('style')
          .attr('type', 'text/css')
          .text(css);

      defs.append('clipPath')
          .attr('id', 'clip-land')
        .append('use')
          .attr('xlink:href', '#land');

  var g = svg.append('g');

      g.attr('clip-path', 'url(#clip-land)')
        .selectAll('path')
          .data(topojson.feature(congress, congress.objects.districts).features)
        .enter().append('path')
          .attr('d', path)
          .attr('class', function(d) { return getColor(d); });

      g.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.mesh(congress, congress.objects.districts, function(a, b) { return a !== b && (a.id / 1000 | 0) === (b.id / 1000 | 0); }))
        .attr('class', 'district-boundaries')
        .attr('d', path);

      g.append('path')
        .datum(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.states, function(a, b) { return a !== b; }))
        .attr('class', 'state-boundaries')
        .attr('d', path);

  // This file cannot be edited:
  var output = d3.select(document.body).html().replace(/clippath/g, 'clipPath');

  // This file can be edited:
  //var output = d3.select(document.body).html();

  fs.writeFileSync(fileName, output);

}
```

Comment: Can you attach or link an example SVG that your program produces?  What does "can't be edited" mean exactly?

Comment: Corrected clipPath: http://dylanist.com/static/output.svg

Uncorrected clipPath: http://dylanist.com/static/output2.svg

By "can't be edited" I mean that, if you open up output.svg in Inkscape, for instance, the only shape that appears is the rectangle. But if you open output2.svg, all paths and shapes appear, just without proper clipping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remaining problem with output2.svg is that the `<use>` reference in your clip path element wasn't correct.

What I did:

1. `<clippath>` -> `<clipPath>`
2. `href="#land"` -> `xlink:href="#land"`
3. Add in the xlink namespace to the root element

   ```
   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="960" height="500">
   ```

Comment: Hm, that definitely seems to be the issue, but I can't figure out why d3/node would be doing that. `attr('xlink:href', '#land')` should be adding an xlink:href attribute, but the generated SVG omits the `xlink` part.

Comment: After some Googling, it appears that the namespace is removed when rendering the SVG on the server. The answer is to add a colon before the namespace. Again, not sure why that's happening, but that's the fix. Thanks for tracking down the incorrect `<use>` reference! https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/291#issuecomment-226988829